# Exclude a page from the Next.js root layout in the app folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a root layout `/app/layout.tsx` and authentication pages. I want the authentication pages NOT to get the root layout, and I defined a custom layout for them in the `/app/auth/layout.tsx` file.

But the root layout(`/app/layout.tsx`) wraps the custom layout(`/app/auth/layout.tsx`). How can I exclude the auth pages and sub-pages from getting the root layout?

I tried putting the auth dir name in `()` as `(auth)` but not working. Most of the solution are for the **Pages Router** and doesn't work for **App Router**.

I'm using Next.js `13.4`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the `app` directory of Next.js, view the root layout as the `index.html` file when using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev) or [Vite](https://vitejs.dev). Your components should render there. This is why it's required and should define `html` and `body` tags, as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#root-layouts) says:

> The `app` directory must include a root `app/layout.js`.
> The root layout must define `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

Also, any parent layout wraps all nested route layouts. If different parts of your application should be different, you can, using [Routes Groups](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups), create [multiple root layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts):

> To create multiple root layouts, remove the top-level `layout.js` file, and add a `layout.js` file inside each route groups. This is useful for partitioning an application into sections that have a completely different UI or experience. The `<html>` and `<body>` tags need to be added to each root layout.

[image]

> In the example above, both `(marketing)` and `(shop)` have their own root layout.

You can, for example, replace `marketing` with `general`, and `shop` with `auth`. Side note, the naming of route groups has no special significance other than for organization. They do not affect the URL path.

Also, routes inside route groups should not resolve to the same URL path. For example, since route groups don't affect URL structure, `(marketing)/about/page.js` and `(shop)/about/page.js` would both resolve to `/about` and cause an error.

Comment: How should I structure my project if I want to use a specific locale and layout.tsx for the majority of my pages, but require a different layout for the 'about' directory? This alternative layout should not include a footer, but it must incorporate the locale and navbar. I attempted to use `(about)`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

When I remove the top-level layout.js I receive: Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\falac\Desktop\frontend\ProjectsInGit\blog-tests\src\app\layout.js'

If you encounter the same issue as mine, you can try the following steps to resolve it:

1. Stop the project.
2. Delete the ".next" folder.
3. Restart the project.

Comment: If you delete the .next folder, wouldn't that throw errors as well?

Comment: Yes it would, but it will be created again after you run `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your top level layout.js and page.js files also into a route group. For example, create a folder named (home) and put them there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).