# How can I use two layouts in one Next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I made a blog project, so I want an admin panel. I don't want to use the global layout in my admin area. How can I use two layouts in one project?

[image]

I tried to make a conditional call in `_app.tsx` but I could not create a loop in "Component".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `pages` folder, you can use what Next.js calls [Per-Page Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#per-page-layouts). And because most pages would use the global `Layout`, you can do as below for your admin:

```
// pages/admin/index.js

import AdminLayout from "./_layout";

export default function Page() {
  return <></>;
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return <AdminLayout>{page}</AdminLayout>;
};
```

```
// pages/_app.js

import Layout from "./_layout";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout;
  if (getLayout) {
    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
  }

  // Otherwise use the global Layout
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

And for future people using the `app` directory, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76251099/exclude-a-page-from-the-next-js-root-layout-in-the-app-folder) would help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I read the documentation, I thought I would use getLayout on every page :') Your answer was very helpful.